# Loading a textfile in FreeMat

Tags: matlab, text, file-io, freemat

I am trying to get my MATLAB code for loading and parsing certain text files to work in FreeMat and have run into difficulties on square one.

The file looks like this:

> 1110000
>
> 1001100
>
> 1000011
>
> 0101010
>
> 0100101
>
> 0011001
>
> 0010110
>
> Number of  7-3-1 designs =      1 Number of designs with |Aut|=    168
>   is        1

textread.m seems to be unknown to FreeMat and calls to load and dlmread haven't done the job either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `textscan`/`textread` are not yet implemented in FreeMat. You can instead read the file line-by-line using [`fgetline`](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/help/io_fgetline.html) (equivalent to [`fgets`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html) in MATLAB).

Here is a list of available [IO functions](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/help/sec_io.html) in FreeMat